# How to format a column before running a where search in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a column with data type datetime. I want to search this column, using `:where` and return results based on a given day. The issue is, the :time_slot column has datetime objects, so I would need to format the column first, before running the search. Any suggestions on how I would this?

```
@movies = @movie_theater.showings.where({:time_slot => params[:day]})
```

Comment: what exactly (example) would be inside `params[:day]`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a scope inside your model

```
scope :on_day, lambda { |day| where('extract(day from time_slot) = ?', day) }
```

which you can later use in your Controller `@movie_theater.showings.on_day('2015-1-1')`

Comment: oh yea, thanks. lets wait for OP better describing the params[:day]

Comment: yea it would need to match the full date, such as 2015-1-1, but just the number of the day